# for loop not working properly in php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my `for` loop. I want to update those records which designMasterId i get in hidden but it is automatically update all records..

Through this hidden text box i am try to pass designmasterId:

```
<input type="hidden" name="designMasterId[]" value="{$designArray[sec].designMasterId}">
```

Php code:

```
   if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
      {
        $recDate       = $_POST['rDtYear']."-".$_POST['rDtMonth']."-".$_POST['rDtDay'];
        $lastProcess   = isset($_POST['processId']) ? $_POST['processId'] : 0;
        $nextProcessId = isset($_POST['nextProcessId']) ? $_POST['nextProcessId'] : 0;

        for($i=0; $i< count($_POST['designMasterId']); $i++)
        {
          $processId       = isset($_POST['processId'][$i]) ? $_POST['processId'][$i] : 0;
          $reciveWet       = isset($_POST['reciveWet'][$i]) ? $_POST['reciveWet'][$i] : 0;
          $designMasterId  = isset($_POST['designMasterId'][$i]) ? $_POST['designMasterId'][$i] : 0;

          $updatePro = "UPDATE process 
                          SET rDate = '".$recDate."',
                              reciveWet = '".$reciveWet."',
                              nextProcessId   = ".$nextProcessId.",
                              processMasterId = ".$nextProcessId.",
                              status = 'I'
                         WHERE designMasterId = ".$designMasterId;
         $updateProRes = mysql_query($updatePro);
         if(!$updateProRes)
          {
            echo "Recive Fail";
          }
          else
          {
            header("Location:processRecive.php");
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: your update query will execute for all for loops.

Comment: yes it's update all records.. @Richie

Comment: `{$designArray[sec].designMasterId}` is that a template code or a php code? If it's php, the dot(.), is it used as concatenation operator or as object-member access operator? If the latter, in php it is `->` not `.`.

Comment: First of all, stop using **MySQL_***, it's depreciated. You should use MySQLi or PDO instead (most recommend PDO). Secondly look at [injection prevention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: template code @mikeO.

Comment: Please clarify the problem - do you mean every record in the table is updated? What is the exact contents of `$_POST['designMasterId']`?

Comment: it's update all records of table it's not considering designMasterId.. @Steve

Comment: i want to update whose records which id i get in while i am submitting form..

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output of `var_dump($_POST['designMasterId']);`

Comment: if you add: _`and nextProcessId   <> ".$nextProcessId."`_ to the where clause then it will only update the changed records rather than every record..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have updated your code check if it works for you..

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        $recDate       = $_POST['rDtYear']."-".$_POST['rDtMonth']."-".$_POST['rDtDay'];
        $lastProcess   = isset($_POST['processId']) ? $_POST['processId'] : 0;
        $nextProcessId = isset($_POST['nextProcessId']) ? $_POST['nextProcessId'] : 0;
    for($i=0; $i< count($_POST['designMasterId']); $i++)
    {
      $processId       = (isset($_POST['processId'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['processId'][$i])) ? $_POST['processId'][$i] : 0;
      $reciveWet       = (isset($_POST['reciveWet'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['reciveWet'][$i])) ? $_POST['reciveWet'][$i] : 0;
      $designMasterId  = (isset($_POST['designMasterId'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['designMasterId'][$i])) ? $_POST['designMasterId'][$i] : 0;

      if(isset($designMasterId) && !empty($designMasterId)){
      $updatePro = "UPDATE process 
                      SET rDate = '".$recDate."',
                          reciveWet = '".$reciveWet."',
                          nextProcessId   = ".$nextProcessId.",
                          processMasterId = ".$nextProcessId.",
                          status = 'I'
                     WHERE designMasterId = ".$designMasterId;
     $updateProRes = mysqli_query($updatePro);
     if(!$updateProRes)
      {
        echo "Recive Fail";
      }
      else
      {
        header("Location:processRecive.php");
      }
      }else{
        continue;
      }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this this will work for you

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

$recDate = $_POST['rDtYear']."-".$_POST['rDtMonth']."-".$_POST['rDtDay']; $lastProcess = isset($_POST['processId']) ? $_POST['processId'] : 0; $nextProcessId = isset($_POST['nextProcessId']) ? $_POST['nextProcessId'] : 0;
for($i=0; $i< count($_POST['designMasterId']); $i++)
{
  $processId       = (isset($_POST['processId'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['processId'][$i])) ? $_POST['processId'][$i] : 0;
  $reciveWet       = (isset($_POST['reciveWet'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['reciveWet'][$i])) ? $_POST['reciveWet'][$i] : 0;
  $designMasterId  = (isset($_POST['designMasterId'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['designMasterId'][$i])) ? $_POST['designMasterId'][$i] : 0;

  if(isset($designMasterId) && !empty($designMasterId)){
  $updatePro = "UPDATE process 
                  SET rDate = '".$recDate."',
                      reciveWet = '".$reciveWet."',
                      nextProcessId   = ".$nextProcessId.",
                      processMasterId = ".$nextProcessId.",
                      status = 'I'
                 WHERE designMasterId = ".$designMasterId;
 $updateProRes = mysqli_query($updatePro);
 if(!$updateProRes)
  {
    echo "Recive Fail";
  }
  else
  {
    header("Location:processRecive.php");
  }
  }else{
    continue;
  }
    }
  }
```

Comment: there is no error but it's update whole records of table

Comment: use this `if(!empty($designMasterId)){`

Comment: same result @Developing Developer

Comment: whats ur expected output ?

Comment: UPDATE process SET rDate = '2016-03-24', reciveWet = '10.230', nextProcessId = 1, processMasterId = 1, status = 'I' WHERE designMasterId = 1
UPDATE process SET rDate = '2016-03-24', reciveWet = '5.260', nextProcessId = 1, processMasterId = 1, status = 'I' WHERE designMasterId = 1
UPDATE process SET rDate = '2016-03-24', reciveWet = '10.230', nextProcessId = 1, processMasterId = 1, status = 'I' WHERE designMasterId = 2
UPDATE process SET rDate = '2016-03-24', reciveWet = '0', nextProcessId = 1, processMasterId = 1, status = 'I' WHERE designMasterId = 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73662/discussion-between-user1866385-and-developing-developer).

Answer (score -1):

> use array_filter in count record for loop

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
      {
        $recDate       = $_POST['rDtYear']."-".$_POST['rDtMonth']."-".$_POST['rDtDay'];
        $lastProcess   = isset($_POST['processId']) ? $_POST['processId'] : 0;
        $nextProcessId = isset($_POST['nextProcessId']) ? $_POST['nextProcessId'] : 0;

        for($i=0; $i< count(array_filter($_POST['designMasterId'])); $i++)
        {
          $processId       = isset($_POST['processId'][$i]) ? $_POST['processId'][$i] : 0;
          $reciveWet       = isset($_POST['reciveWet'][$i]) ? $_POST['reciveWet'][$i] : 0;
          $designMasterId  = isset($_POST['designMasterId'][$i]) ? $_POST['designMasterId'][$i] : 0;

          $updatePro = "UPDATE process 
                          SET rDate = '".$recDate."',
                              reciveWet = '".$reciveWet."',
                              nextProcessId   = ".$nextProcessId.",
                              processMasterId = ".$nextProcessId.",
                              status = 'I'
                         WHERE designMasterId = ".$designMasterId;
         $updateProRes = mysql_query($updatePro);
         if(!$updateProRes)
          {
            echo "Recive Fail";
          }
          else
          {
            header("Location:processRecive.php");
          }
        }
      }
?>
```

Comment: same result is there any my mistake in my hidden.. @Navjot Singh